# .bashrc unexpected end of file

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks, unexpectendoffile

I've searched and found several answers but I didn't succeed in altering mine.

Operating system : Mac OS X

My .bashrc content

```
# Before other PATHs...
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/share/python

alias la='ls -la'

function find_cpp_filepath_with_string { find $1 -name "*.cpp" -type f -exec  grep -l $2 {} \;}

#export -f find_cpp_filepath_with_string

else
    echo "WARNING: Can't find virtualenvwrapper.sh"
fi
```

The troublesome line is the following

```
function find_cpp_filepath_with_string { find $1 -name "*.cpp" -type f -exec  grep -l $2 {} \;}
```

after trying source ~/.bashrc the result is :

```
line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: The .bashrc is really complete here?

Comment: I removed some more path variables that were commented out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct when you say that the `troublesome line is the following`.  You are missing a semicolon.  Say:

> `function find_cpp_filepath_with_string { find $1 -name "*.cpp" -type f
>   -exec  grep -l $2 {} \; ; }`
>
> ```
>                 ^
>                 |-----  You need to add a semicolon here!
> ```

The first semicolon is required to denote the end of `-exec` for the `find` command.  The second one is required following the [command group](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping).

Comment: I was so close, tried ;; instead of ; ;. Thank you very much !